# Filter DataGridView - Strange behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I wanted to filter my DataGridView on value of a selected tree node representing file numbers, i.e. .85, 200, 404.005, and etc...

I started with:

```
bs.Filter = "FMFileNumber = " 
          + e.Node.Text.Substring(0, e.Node.Text.IndexOf(" - ")).ToString();
```

but that gave me the following exception when the value was an integer  (don't know why it was seen as integer in the first place):

```
{"Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32."}
```

I read on one blog here to convert inside the filter so I changed to:

```
bs.Filter = string.Format("FMFileNumber =  convert({0}, System.String)",
                    e.Node.Text.Substring(0, e.Node.Text.IndexOf("  - ")).ToString());
```

This seems to work okay for values with a number left of decimal but not not for values that led with decimal.  In the latter case I got a blank datagridview.

Why?   Is there a more reliable way to filter?

```
        getFileAndColumns();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        dgvColumns.DataSource = tbltAttributes;
        bs.DataSource = dgvColumns.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("FMFileNumber =  convert({0}, System.String)",
            e.Node.Text.Substring(0, e.Node.Text.IndexOf("  - ")).ToString());
        //bs.Filter = "FMFileNumber = " + e.Node.Text.Substring(0, e.Node.Text.IndexOf(" - ")).ToString();
        dgvColumns.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: What's the type of the `FMFileNumber` member? If it's `int`, then you should probably not compare integers as strings in the first place.

Comment: Part of the question is why is it being seen as integer.  It's varchar when it comes from SQL.  If it was integer don't you think an exception would be thrown on numbers with decimal?

tbltAttributes.Columns[0].DataType = System.String  (FMFileNumber type)

Comment: In your original code, we know that the right side of the equation is definitely a `string`, even without calling `ToString()` because the `Substring(int, int)` overload returns a `string`. So the question is then: Why would FMFileNumber be interpreted as an `Int32` ? That's something we can only answer by having the relevant portion of code where we can see where `FMFileNumber` comes from and how it is declared....

Comment: Also, if it's `FMFileNumber` which is the problem, have you tried using the `convert` function on that instead of the other side of the equation ?

Comment: Maybe we're not on the same page.  There is a datatable with column FMFileNumber but in the filter I'm setting the value for FMFileNumber to a substring of a treenode and then using that to filter dgvColumns/FMFileNumber.

Isn't it the value extracted from treenode that is causing problem?

Comment: I can get around this by conditionally creating the filter as follows:
if (b) bs.Filter = "FMFileNumber = " + e.Node.Text.Substring(0, e.Node.Text.IndexOf(" - ")).ToString();
                else bs.Filter = string.Format("FMFileNumber =  convert({0}, System.String)",
                    e.Node.Text.Substring(0, e.Node.Text.IndexOf("  - ")).ToString());